# How to analyse data set of information using bash?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I have got a data set:

```
16   
18
1
24
7
13
13
24
17
15
10
16
2
16
11
21
15
24
6
13
2
2
21
16
8
16
11
0
19
```

*Background:* These values represent the number of hours a device is operating per given day. I have about a months worth of data presented above, and the company has requested of me to 'analyse' this data, ie see if any patterns are emerging. Ideally I would like to use bash to write a code that can do this for me - but I don't know how to do it.

*Research:* I have looked at various question in analysing data. Using a [counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418403/best-way-to-analyse-data-using-ruby) could work, other suggestions include [machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423045/how-to-analyse-and-predictmachine-learning-a-time-series-data-set-using-scikit), but this may be too difficult in bash.

*My Approach:* I'm thinking of having two parameters (*a*) easy working (<=12hrs) & (*b*) hard working (>12hrs). So the code then compare the pattern of *a* and *b*, so then the data would be for example, *aaaabbababaababba*, so from this the software should be able to recognize if a pattern is emerging - or there is a pattern present.

**Questions:** **(Q1)** How can I make software 'realize' a pattern is emerging? **(Q2)** Can such software be written in bash? **(Q3)** Is there a better approach to mine? **(Q4)** What would be a better language to write such a code in?

Comment: Why would you use bash for this? Python, R even Java are better choices for data analysis.

Comment: @Nick Bailey I'm not too proficient in them.

Comment: @3kstc: that doesn't matter.  What matters is you figure out *what* you want to do, then later *how* to do it.  So far you have a data science problem: how to analyze this data.  Once you've figured that out, the answer will still be "don't use Bash" unless the analysis is extremely simple.  Python is the easiest to learn for this sort of thing, and it is just as powerful as anything else.

Comment: It's easier to learn python then to do data analysis in bash.

Comment: I would want to add the dates to this. Then you could see if end-of-month, weekends, etc are different and present challenges or "opportunites" ;-) . Can't you just paste it into Excel and play with it there? Pattern recognition software is a very advanced topic, and even as much as I love shells, I don't see that it would be possible to write anything beyond a kindergarten analysis in shell (compared to R or Python, yes ... and many others). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter <!> That's exactly what I did, the information I gather is stored every 24 hours into a csv file - so playing around with the data was simple. My code that stores the information via the cronjob has been doing so for about 28 days. in 3 months time, i would like this patterns to recongnized by software - well thats the goal anyway- and get fortnighly emails about the trend patterns.